# Android app on Market - from trial version to full version without 2 apks

Tags: android, google-play

I need to implement in my app:
FULL Version (while trial) -> LITE Version (after trial period ends) -> FULL Version (if user pays using InApp Purchase).

I want user will not have to Uninstall and re-install the Full app

anyone have experience doing something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer already lies in your question. *As you said user is allowed to use FULL version for some specified time period for trial purpose and then can use FULL version only if they pay for it using InApp payment*, **so you require to put a check in your application launch activity, whether app is still in TRIAL period or whether user has PAID for FULL Version, if not either of the case disable functionalities which should only be supported in your FULL VERSION and it becomes LITE Version**.

Comment: This is understood. It is easy to implement, the question is: Do google allows it?

Comment: check this [link](https://developer.android.com/distribute/monetize/freemium.html). I do not thing by implementing trial period you are violating any google play policies. Possible mention this in your application description, so user know about this before downloading.

Comment: Thanks for the link. there seems to be no problem about it. Thanks again!